# Export original as @3x in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In Photoshop CC we can export an image and also export the @2x @3x etc. This is obviously assuming that the original was made at the @1x size.

Is it possible to say what the original is and export the others? For instance can I create my asset as @3x and then export choose to create the @2x and @1x? Downsizing rather than upscaling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original is **always** @x1 size.
Whatever size it is, that's your @x1 size,

If you want that to be your Master & save downsized versions, then export those at 0.66x & 0.33x. [or more significant figures if necessary, 0.66667, 0.33333]

Comment: Ah thanks, I wasn't aware we could do custom sizes

Comment: @Tetsujin depends on size of your image offcourse.

Comment: @Tetsujin 0.33333 obviously does not cause any pixewl alignemt issues unless your image is really big, in which case the rounding error your using will catch you.

Comment: @Tetsujin no but if you start with a 10000 or 100000 pixel wide image then it is a a issue. THe rounding will eventually catch up. Im not saying theres anything wrong just saying that the rounding will eventually be an issue if your size is LARGE. And really 300 pixels is really small for eve web design thesedays

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75772/discussion-between-joojaa-and-tetsujin).

Comment: Comments removed. Pointless edge-case discussion in link above.